# Mysql json.dump() line break indentation for viewing

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json, python-3.x

I am using the following line of code for executing and printing data from my sql database. For some reason that is the only command that works for me.

```
json_string = json.dumps(location_query_1)
```

My question is that when I print json_string it shows data in the following format:

[image]

Actions.py code:

```
class FindByLocation(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_find_by_location"

    def run (self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            doman: Dict[Text, Any])-> List[Dict[Text,Any]]:

        global flag
        location =  tracker.get_slot("location")
        price = tracker.get_slot("price")
        cuisine = tracker.get_slot("cuisine")
        print("In find by Location")
        print(location)
        location_query = "SELECT Name FROM Restaurant WHERE Location = '%s' LIMIT 5" % location
        location_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM Restaurant WHERE Location = '%s'" % location

        location_query_1 = getData(location_query)
        location_count_query_1 = getData(location_count_query)

        if not location_query_1:
            flag = 1
            sublocation_view_query = "CREATE VIEW SublocationView AS SELECT RestaurantID, Name, PhoneNumber, Rating, PriceRange, Location, Sublocation FROM Restaurant WHERE Sublocation = '%s'"%(location)
            sublocation_view = getData(sublocation_view_query)
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="یہ جگہ کس ایریا میں ہے")
        else:
            flag = 0


            if cuisine is None and price is None:

                json_string = json.dumps(location_query_1)
                print(isinstance(json_string, str))
                print("Check here")

                list_a=json_string.split(',')
                remove=["'",'"','[',']']

                for i in remove:
                    list_a=[s.replace(i, '') for s in list_a]


                dispatcher.utter_message(text="Restaurants in Location only: ")
                dispatcher.utter_message(list_a)
```

What should I do se that the data is showed in a vertical list format (new line indentation) and without the bracket and quotation marks? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have you tried reading your data into a pandas object? I have done some programs with a sqlite database and this worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {}".format(self.tablename), conn)
```

But now to the string formatting part:

```
# this code should do the work for you
# first of all we have our string a like yours
a="[['hallo'],['welt'],['kannst'],['du'],['mich'],['hoeren?']]"
# now we split the string into a list on every ,
list_a=a.split(',')
# this is our list with chars we want to remove
remove=["'",'"','[',']']

# now we replace all elements step by step with nothing
for i in remove:
    list_a=[s.replace(i, '') for s in list_a]

print(list_a)
for z in list_a:
    print(z)
```

The output is then:

```
['hallo', 'welt', 'kannst', 'du', 'mich', 'hoeren?']
hallo
welt
kannst
du
mich
hoeren?
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try the panda way as well.

Comment: Yeah with pandas it could be easier. No problem

Comment: Every time I try to run this:
>>       list_a=json_string.split(',')
It gives me an error saying:
 for message_part in text.strip().split("\n\n"):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Okay that's strange could you maybe share your full code. Maybe I understand then what happens? Maybe on GitHub or something like this.

Comment: Okay, I think your string is is somehow not right. Could you print the string out and share that output again, please ? Or maybe try to add list_a=str(json_string).split(',').

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211818/discussion-between-zaid-alvi-and-sebnik).